# How do I assign a string from one position to another in an Array with input (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want a person to give me the input:"A, C" and the integer in the 0th position in my Array has to go to the 2th position. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.scanner;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String[] Example = {"value", "", ""} ;
int A = 0;
int B = 1;
int C = 2;


string first = sc.nextStr();        //first position of the array gets inputted(A)
string second = sc.nextStr();       //second position of the array gets inputted(C)

Example[first] = Example[second];   //it should do what I wanted but the Inputs are "A" and "C" 
                                    //and it would not work because there is no Example["A"], instead
                                    // my code has to use the variables that I created before

System.out.println(Example[2])
```

The output should be "variable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read in an index as an `int`.  Arrays are indexed by ints, not by strings.

```
int first = sc.nextInt();        
int second = sc.nextInt();  

Example[first] = Example[second];
```

If you want to index using a String, you need to use a map.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", "someValue1");
map.put("B", "someValue2");
map.put("C", "someValue3");

String first = sc.next();
String second = sc.next();

map.put(first, map.get(second));
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!! the Map is the thing I need.